# Least square approximation of an ellipse with fixed center

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-methods, conic-sections

I was thinking about the problem of fitting scattered data to an ellipse with a fixed center (i.e. the center is given in advance) using least square. I found [a paper by Fittzgibbon et al.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ellipse-pami.pdf) which approximate an ellipse using least square but the center is not fixed in advance. I was wondering if it is possible to modify the method for a constrained center. Any other reference paper for a solution is also welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicit equation of an ellipse is

$ (r - r_0)^T Q (r - r_0) = 1$

where $r_0= (r_{01}, r_{02})$ is the center, and $Q$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.  Since $r_0$ is given in advance, we will shift all the coordinates of the given points, by adding the negative of $r_0$, i.e. we define $ r' = r - r_0 $, then the equation of the ellipse to be identified will be,

$ r'^T Q r' = 1 $

After completing the shift, let $ r'_i = (x_i, y_i) $, then the above equation expands to

$ \epsilon_i = A x_i^2 + B y_i^2 + C x_i y_i + D  $

We have to add an additional constraint to the unknowns $A,B,C,D$ that will guarantee that they are NOT all zero.  A convenient condition is that $A + B = 1$

Note that the least squares function (to be minimized) is

$ J = \displaystyle \sum_i \epsilon_i^2 $

Substituting the condition on $A$ and $B$, we get

$ J = \displaystyle \sum_i \left( x_i^2 + B ( y_i^2 - x_i^2 ) + C x_i y_i + D \right)^2 $

Next we find $\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial B}$, $\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial C}$, $\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial D}$ and this will give the so-called normal equations for the least squares regression.  These are given by

$\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial B}= 2 \displaystyle \sum_i (y_i^2 - x_i^2) \left( x_i^2 + B ( y_i^2 - x_i^2 ) + C x_i y_i + D \right) =0$

$\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial C}= 2 \displaystyle \sum_i (x_i y_i) \left( x_i^2 + B ( y_i^2 - x_i^2 ) + C x_i y_i + D \right) =0$

$\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial D}= 2 \displaystyle \sum_i \left( x_i^2 + B ( y_i^2 - x_i^2 ) + C x_i y_i + D \right) =0$

We now have a linear system of three equation in the three unknowns $B, C, D$, which is straight forward to solve numerically.  Once $B,C,D$ are found, then $A = 1 - B $ is now known.

What is left is to find $Q$, and for that, note that

$ A = t Q_{11} $

$ B = t Q_{22} $

$ C = 2 t Q_{12} $

$ D = -t $

The last equation gives us the value of the multiplier $t$. So that $Q$ is now determined.

The final form of the ellipse is obtained by shifting the found ellipse so that its center is at $r_0$, and this will make its equation:

$ (r - r_0)^T Q (r - r_0) = 1 $

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have two follow up questions : 1) When you say "the above equation expands to $\epsilon_i=Ax^2_i+By^2_i+Cx_iy_i+D$" wouldn't the above equation expand to $Ax^2_i+By^2_i+Cx_iy_i+D=0$? 2) Isn't $Q$ just $\begin{bmatrix}A & \frac{1}{2}C\\\frac{1}{2}C & D\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: As for the first question, $\epsilon_i$ is the "equation error" associated with the  $i$-th observation.  As for the second quesion, the answer is no.  The entries of $Q$ are multiples of $A, B,C$.  They are not equal to them.  This is because we imposed $A+B=1$

Comment: still I don't understand why the above equation is not $A x_i^2+By_i^2+Cx_i y_i = 1$? Did you take $D=-1$?

Comment: From $r^T Q r = 1 $, you get $ Q_{11} x_i^2 + 2 Q_{12} x_i y_i + Q_{22} y_i^2 - 1 = 0 $.  Now if you multiply this by a non-zero constant $t$, it becomes $ t Q_{11} x_i^2 + 2 t Q{12} x_i y_i + t Q_{22} y_i^2 - t = 0 $.  The form we have is $ A x_i^2 + B y_i^2 + C x_i y_i + D = 0 $.  Comparing the two, we deduce that $D = - t$ , that is $ t = - D $, now we can find $Q_{11} = A / t , Q_{22} = B / t , Q_{12} = \frac{1}{2} C / t $